# Differentation of vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

in the below equation, $\mathbf w$ is a vector with components $w_0$ and $w_1$.
$x^{(i)}$ and $y^{(i)}$ are constants.

how to differentiate $j(\mathbf w)$ w.r.t. $w_0$ and $w_1$

$j(\mathbf w) = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks. looks better now.

Comment: you mean $j(\mathbf w) = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)$ or $j(\mathbf w) = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)^2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting
$$
\nabla j(\mathbf{w})=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial j}{\partial w_0}\\
\dfrac{\partial j}{\partial w_1}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
if $j(\mathbf w) = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
\nabla j(\mathbf{w})=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial j}{\partial w_0}\\
\dfrac{\partial j}{\partial w_1}
\end{pmatrix} &=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial }{\partial w_0}\bigg[\displaystyle\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)\bigg]\\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_1}\bigg[\displaystyle\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)\bigg]
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5(-1)\\
\displaystyle\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5y^{(i)}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2}\\
\displaystyle\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5y^{(i)}
\end{pmatrix},
\end{split}
$$
while if $j(\mathbf w) = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)^2$
$$
\begin{split}
\nabla j(\mathbf{w})=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial j}{\partial w_0}\\
\dfrac{\partial j}{\partial w_1}
\end{pmatrix} &=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial }{\partial w_0}\bigg[\displaystyle\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)^2\bigg]\\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_1}\bigg[\displaystyle\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^5(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)^2\bigg]
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle-\frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=1}^5(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)\\
\displaystyle\frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=1}^5y^{(i)}(x^{(i)}+w_1y^{(i)}-w_0)
\end{pmatrix},
\end{split}
$$
The method is always the same: *you should differentiate termwise each term of the sum*. This is also true if you want to calculate mixed derivatives (that in this case are invariant respect to the order of differentiation)
$$
\dfrac{\partial^2 j(\mathbf{w})}{\partial w_0\partial w_1}=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial w_0}\bigg[\dfrac{\partial j(\mathbf{w})}{\partial w_1}\bigg]=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial w_1}\bigg[\dfrac{\partial j(\mathbf{w})}{\partial w_0}\bigg]=\dfrac{\partial^2 j(\mathbf{w})}{\partial w_1\partial w_0}
$$
or, if $(w_0,w_1)=\big(w_0(t),w_1(t)\big)$, you want to calculate the *total derivative respect to $t$*:
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d} j(\mathbf{w})}{\mathrm{d}t}=\dfrac{\partial j(\mathbf{w})}{\partial w_0}\dfrac{\mathrm{d} w_0(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}+\dfrac{\partial j(\mathbf{w})}{\partial w_1}\dfrac{\mathrm{d} w_1(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The differential of the sum is the sum of differential.

Then comes a square, use the power rule $(u^2)' = 2 u u'$.